# What is the need for caret (^) and dollar symbol ($) in regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have read recently about JavaScript regular expressions, but I am confused.

The author says that it is necessary to include the caret (`^`) and dollar symbol (`$`) at the beginning and end of the all regular expressions declarations.

Why are they needed?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Javascript RegExp() allows you to specify a multi-line mode (m) which changes the behavior of `^` and `$`.

`^` represents the **start of the current line in multi-line mode**, otherwise the start of the string

`$` represents the **end of the current line in multi-line mode**, otherwise the end of the string

For example: this allows you to match something like semicolons at the end of a line where the next line starts with "var" `/;$\n\s*var/m`

Fast regexen also need an "anchor" point, somewhere to start it's search somewhere in the string. These characters tell the Regex engine where to start looking and generally reduce the number of backtracks, making your Regex **much, much faster** in many cases.

NOTE: This knowledge came from Nicolas Zakas's [High Performance Javascript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059680279X)

Conclusion: **You should use them!**

Comment: what do you mean by multi-line mode?

Comment: @Ant's It means match each line of a multi-line string *separately* - check it out at regexpal.com

Comment: Yup thanks for your answer ;) mainly for saying that using anchors will help regex engine ;) thank you ;)

Comment: You're welcome, and BTW I *highly* recommend you read Zakas book :)

Comment: i was in interest to read an book on data structures, after seeing your site i come to conclusion that i can read "The Algorithm Design Manual" :) ;)

Comment: Zakas book? Can you say me the title and author name ;)

Comment: Nicolas Zakas, High Performance Javascript - link is in my answer :)

Comment: Does that mean that I can skip the `^` and `$` characters in my regular expression if I know that the input string I'm going to test has only one line i.e. it is not broken over multiple lines?

Comment: @RBT you can skip them but it makes the pattern matching stricter and  possibly faster, which is _usually_ what you want.

Comment: Don't you mean you should use them when appropriate? What if you're trying to match something that's not at the beginning or end of a string?

Answer (score 13):

`^` represents the start of the input string.

`$` represents the end.

You don't actually have to use them at the start and end. You can use em anywhere =) Regex is fun (and confusing). They don't represent a character. They represent the start and end.

[This is a very good website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 5):

They match the start of the string (`^`) and end of the string ('$').

You should use them when matching strings at the start or end of the string. I wouldn't say you *have* to use them, however.

Answer (score 4):

I have tested these.

1. `/^a/` matches abb, ab but not ba, bab, bba.

2. `/a/` matches abb, ab and ba, bab, bba.

I think that `/^a/` matches such strings starting a.

`/a/` matches such strings contains a.

Similar to `/^a/`, `/a$/` matches ba, a, but not ab, bab.

Refer http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html .

If you notify wrong(or strange) sentence in above or this to me, I would thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`^` anchors the beginning of the RE at the start of the test string, and `$` anchors the end of the RE at the end of the test string. If that's what you want, go for it! However, if you're using REs of the form `^.*theRealRE.*$` then you might want to consider dropping the anchors and just using the core of the RE on its own.

Some languages force REs to be anchored at both ends by default.