# add query conditions using mongoose model

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

using Node.js, Mongoose Schema and MongoDB,

the user model Schema is

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

    var userSchema = new Schema({
        name:             { type: String, trim: true }
      , address:          { type: String }
      , birth:            { type: Date }
      , tlf:              { type: String }
      , email:            { type: String, lowercase: true }
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

and the function to query users with conditions (var cond), select (var sel), options (var opts) is

```
 findAllUsers = function (req, res, next) {
    var cond = {
      name : req.query.nm

    };
    var sel = 'name address';
    var opts = { 
        skip: req.query.sk, limit: req.query.lim, sort: req.query.srt
    };

    User.find(cond, sel, opts).lean().exec(function (err, users) {
        if (err) next(err);
        var body = {};
        body.skip = req.query.sk;
        body.limit = req.query.lim;
        body.users= users;

        User.count(cond).exec(function (err, total) {
            if (err) next(err);
             body.total = total;
            res.json(body);
          });
      });
  }
```

and then, what is the best way to create a conditions with regexp, like, or... ?

Comment: What conditions exactly? You really are not saying exactly what you want to do.

Comment: address like %calle% or like %via% ...

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to "like" in MongoDB is the [**`regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator and would be implemented like this:

```js
db.collection.find({ "address": { "$regex": "via" } });
```

Keep in mind though, that just the same as the equivalent `like "%via%"` statement, this **does** need to *scan* every document in the collection (or at best index) in order to match the string that is not ["anchored"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921699/what-is-the-need-for-caret-and-dollar-symbol-in-regular-expression-in-js) to the **start** of the string.

Comment: in this function the name is required through the browser using like that http://localhost:8080/users?nm=Edu, but is there anyway to show all users if I type http://localhost:8080/users otherwise show one user if I Type http://localhost:8080/users?nm=Edu ???

Comment: @Eduardo I have no idea what you are trying to say. Can you possibly explain exactly what you want to do in your question? I asked you that originally.

Comment: Sorry Neil, I didnt explain correctly, after the use regular expressions inside my var cond{"name":{"$regex": req.query.nm}, I have another question and the other question is =   in the  findAllUsers function the name is required through the browser using like that localhost:8080/users?nm=Edu, but is there anyway to show all users if I type localhost:8080/users or show one user if I Type localhost:8080/users?nm=Edu ???