# Ui-router route parameter with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I feel like this is simple but I can't get it to work...

I am using [Ui-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) 2.11 which includes optional parameters  [with regex expressions.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters)

I have this url which **works**

`'/event/{eventId:[0-9]}'`

it filters out everything that isn't numeric, however it only works for 1 character of input (so only 0 through 9).

I want to replace it with an expression that checks to make sure all characters in the input are numeric so I can have any input as long as it's all numbers.

I tried using expressions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011524/javascript-regexp-number-only-check)

`'/event/{eventId:^[0-9]+$}'`

but it doesn't work. The other examples include forward slashes which I can't use(via the [warning](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters) in the ui-router docs). This feels like it should be incredibly simple, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try removing the $ sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging by the linked documentation, I think either one of these expressions will do the trick:

```
'/event/{eventId:[0-9]+}'//match 1 or more digit
'/event/{eventId:[0-9]{1,}}'//same as above, alternative notation
```

If possible, I would replace `[0-9]` with `\d`, though. It just looks cleaner.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Why does the dollar sign trip it up though? [From what I can tell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921699/what-is-the-need-for-caret-and-dollar-symbol-in-regular-expression-in-js) it's supposed to signify the end of the string -- is it because I may have more input in the URL after the parameter I'm looking for?

Comment: @MattFoxxDuncan: I'm looking through the source ATM. Your patterns are escaped like so: ` var result = string.replace(/[\\\[\]\^$*+?.()|{}]/g, "\\$&");`. It would seem that the `$` sign is actually escaped, matching a literal `$`. Likely because the parameter needn't be the end of the URI (trailing slashes, GET params or a `#` anchor should be allowed). Not sure yet, though. Either way, you're defining rules. If the rule is `\d+`, that's enough: the value must be all-numeric. Beginning and end of the string are irrelevant in that respect