# url.py in django, what does ^ do?

Tags: python, regex, django, url-routing

So ive just started learning django and im currently messing around with the urls.py file. I was wondering if someone could explain to me what the "^" at the start of the url does? I posted some code too if what I said doesnt make sense.

```
url(r'^$', post_timeline),
```

Comment: Not really a Python question. It's Regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921699/what-is-the-need-for-caret-and-dollar-symbol-in-regular-expression-in-js

Comment: I could be wrong, but `^$` means any empty path. You could also use `r'/'`, I think

Answer (score 4):

In urls.py,

```
^ means the start of the URL string and $ is the end of the URL.
```

For example:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^some_base_path/', include('your_app.urls', namespace='your_app')),
]
```

And in urls.py of your app :

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^some_url$', your_app.some_view),

)
```

Here in the second URL, **r'^some_url$'** means start at some_url and $ means that the URL ends here.NO further URL string can be added to it.

Answer (score 0):

Django uses Regular Expressions to identify URL. 
**^** always means the start of the Url and **$** means the end of the Url.